# How to stop multiple notification/duplicate posts on my wall when posting in several groups

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I have joined many groups related to my line of work. When I make a post on any of these groups, Facebook automatically publishes a copy of that post to my wall which says “gurung posted in some group”. When I post the same post in several groups, Facebook publishes the same post again on my wall.

I am sure this pisses off my friends—the same post appears on their wall multiple times. I magine I posted on 10 groups, then there are 10 posts appearing on my wall that says. “gurung posted in 10 groups” and shows multiple copy of same post. I have tried to find a solution to this on Facebook and have hit a dead end.

Any idea how I can stop this?